# Copy lines and increment the number in the variable, using a Vim Script

Tags: vim

I would like to modify the lines of a file that contains variable place-holders, which are numbered sequentially.  More specifically, I would like to add more of these lines with a Vim script.

I would like to copy and paste each of these lines, a specific number of times, and increment the number in the variable as the new lines are added.

I don't really know what I'm doing ...  But with a lot of searching, I was able to cobble together, the command below.

```
%g/06/s/-[0-9]\zs6\ze[>-]/\=(submatch(0)+1)/g
```

It will replace the specified number, with an increment of that specified number.

But it simply modifies the line.  I want to keep the original line, and put a copy of the original line, with the incremented number.  And do this for a specified number of times.

Example:

Find all lines like these ...

```
blah-blah <blah-variable-x-06> <blah-variable-z-06-blah>

a diff line <diff-variable-x-06> <diff-variable-z-06-diff>
```

And make them like this.

```
blah-blah <blah-variable-x-06> <blah-variable-z-06-blah>
blah-blah <blah-variable-x-07> <blah-variable-z-07-blah>
blah-blah <blah-variable-x-08> <blah-variable-z-08-blah>
```

etc ... until a specified number of lines is reached.

```
a diff line <diff-variable-x-06> <diff-variable-z-06-diff>
a diff line <diff-variable-x-07> <diff-variable-z-07-diff>
a diff line <diff-variable-x-08> <diff-variable-z-08-diff>
```

etc ... until a specified number of lines is reached.

Is this possible?  If so, can it be scripted?

Answer (score 0):

would you be okay with a solution that doesn't use a script, but rather records and repeats your keystrokes?

For the given example:

```
blah-blah <blah-variable-x-06> <blah-variable-z-06-blah>
```

We'll start by beginning the recording and putting it in register j (that's my go-to; pick whichever you prefer).  Then we'll copy the line and paste it below.  Then run a regex to increment your vars, and then finish the recorded script.

```
qj
yy
p
:s/variable-[a-zA-Z]-\zs[0-9]*\ze/\=(submatch(0) + 1)/g
q
```

From there, you can move the cursor over the line you wish to perform the operation on and run the script as many times as you wish: `<n>@j` such that `<n>` is the number of lines you wish to create.  You will have to modify the regex to fit the actual structure of your lines rather than the given examples.

Caveat: this isn't perfect.  Your numbers such as `07` will become `7`, so there will still be some work left for you to clean up, but at least the number of occurrences of such values will be capped rather low.

alternatively, if your lines are going to be rather similarly laid out such that you'll always have two of these such variables, you can search for these vars and increment them.  You'll have to tell it not to do octal so it doesn't increment `07` to `10`.  Also, since you are using a hyphen before your numbers, we'll actually have to decrement since it sees them as negative numbers.

```
qk
:let b:nrformats=&nrformats
:set nrformats=bin
yy
p
/variable-[a-zA-Z]-\zs[0-9]*\ze
<c-x>
n
<c-x>
:let &nrformats=b:nrformats
q
```

Again, you'll have to fix the search to properly match your actual usage.

Comment: Christian, thank you for your response.  This solution did not work for me.  I will post further comments and things I've tried.  I still did not find a solution though.